# Expiration formula in excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have qualifications that I need to track for work. When an employee gets that qual, they are current for 180 days. I'd like to understand the formula for when a date is in a cell, the cell next to it will say "Current for X remaining days". On the last day it would say "Last day of currency remaining" and then the next day and until the employee recurrents themselves it would say "Expired"

I tried setting up conditional formatting with it to change colors from green at 60+ days out, yellow for 31-59 days out, orange for 0-30, and red for expired but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: Instead of having one cell/column that says "current for x days", I would create a sole cell/column just for keeping the count, as that's what Excel is more for (as a data holding entity instead of a display/UI entity). Create conditional formatting for this cell and create another cell based off of this cell that converts it into your desired "output" string using if statements

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1+180-TODAY(),{-1E+99,0,1}),"Expired","Last Day","Current for " & A1+180-TODAY() & " Days")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome everyone. Thank you for the replies. I’ll try tomorrow at work and see if I can get them to work!

Answer (score 1):

In an adjacent cell, use this formula,

```
=TODAY()-A2
```

... then use a custom number format (ctrl+1) of,

```
[color10]"Current for "0" remaining days";[color3]"Expired";[color13]"Last day of currency remaining";
```

The bonus to this approach is that the raw underlying number representing the days is available to be referenced in additional formulas/functions. Note the default right alignment of the cells; this shows that the cells contain numbers.

[image]